# Python sqlite3 saving data

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite, save

Does anyone know how do I correct this as this code is not saving the data in a database?

```
def save():

    #FUNCTIONS

    def savenow():
        params = [i.get(), n.get(), p.get(), r.get(), t.get(), a.get(), "None", "None"]

        if not os.path.exists("C:/Users/Dhruv/DS"):
            os.makedirs("C:/Users/Dhruv/DS/")

        connect = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Dhruv/DS/data.db")
        connect.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FD 
                        (ID TEXT NOT NULL,
                         NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                         P INT NOT NULL,
                         R INT,
                         T INT,
                         A INT NOT NULL,
                         D1 DATE,
                         D2 DATE);""")

        tobeexec = "INSERT INTO FD(ID, NAME, P, R, T, A, D1, D2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

        connect.execute(tobeexec, params);

        connect.close()
```

I just want to write the data in the database but when I am trying to retrieve it, it shows that the database is empty...
Anyway thanks in advance...

Comment: try: `connect.commit()` before you close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [commit the transaction](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit).

```
connect.execute(tobeexec, params);
connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the best answer, think also to the use of the *Connection* object as a context manager, it can be useful and it is provided in the [SQLite3 API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) :

```
connect = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Dhruv/DS/data.db")
try:
    with connect:
        connect.execute(...)  # Your SQL statement
except Exception as err:
    # Do what you want with the Exception
```

If your statement(s) within the `with connect` don't raise error, the transaction will be committed automatically. If something goes wrong the transaction is rolled back.

(Another answer could be to set the *isolation_level* to *None* after loading the db, which will implies an **autocommit** mode)

Comment: Actually, `connect.commit()` is a lot better.

Comment: I do not want to needlessly argue on what is the best answer (knowing that my answer was only a complement to the first/best answer), but i'm curious (really!), on which facts do you base your view that `connect.commit()` is *"a lot better"* than the manager context? Or have you an example ? According to the doc the use of the context manager `with` is just a convenient way to automatically call `connect.commit()` when no error is encountered or `connect.rollback()` otherwise.